# How to play RTSP stream in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently facing a problem in the React project, which is how to play RTSP streaming videos on the React page, which is causing me a headache

I tried using React Player, VideoJs, and other libraries, but none of them were implemented

Comment: Hey usually it's good to share the exact symptoms of your problem, but headache is a tough one to help narrow down the core issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.